# Why my sql statement works on command line but not with mysqli_query on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a sql query that works on command line (in my case, running the query using a GUI), but on PHP, through mysqli_query() function, it doesn't work. The error is a duplicate key error.

The bizarre is: the error doesn't exist. The fact that it runs on command line prove that. Also, after further investigation, the records has shown that the unique key was never broken. Though, mysqli_query() throws the unique key error.

My query is:

```
UPDATE
   frequencia 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            *,
            @row_number_aux : = 
            CASE
               WHEN
                  @atual_aux = disciplina_id 
               THEN
                  @row_number_aux + 1 
               ELSE
                  1 
            END
            AS "row_number", @atual_aux : = disciplina_id AS "disciplina_atual" 
         FROM
            frequencia 
         WHERE
            frequencia.data > "2019-06-17" 
            AND frequencia.aluno_id IN 
            (
               8835, 5553, 3488, 7769, 143, 4406, 1472, 698, 8731, 5221, 4240, 4934, 8426, 8107, 5180, 2146, 5589, 4565
            )
      )
      frequencia_aux 
      ON frequencia.id = frequencia_aux.id 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            *,
            @row_number : = 
            CASE
               WHEN
                  @atual = disciplina_id 
               THEN
                  @row_number + 1 
               ELSE
                  1 
            END
            AS "row_number", @atual : = disciplina_id AS "disciplina_atual" 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  disciplina_id,
                  data,
                  tempo,
                  turma_id 
               FROM
                  frequencia 
               WHERE
                  data > "2019-06-17" 
                  AND turma_id = "87" 
               GROUP BY
                  data,
                  disciplina_id,
                  tempo 
            )
            frequencia 
      )
      aux 
      ON frequencia_aux.disciplina_id = aux.disciplina_id 
      AND frequencia_aux.data = aux.data 
      AND frequencia_aux.row_number = aux.row_number 
SET
   frequencia.turma_id = aux.turma_id,
   frequencia.tempo = aux.tempo;
```

I already used the @ variables before with no problems, and all type of complex statements, and never got an error like this. Does anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Duplicate entry '522-143-87-7-2019-2019-06-22-3' for key 'uk_frequencia_tudo'

Comment: The UK takes 7 field in consideration

Comment: Are the user-defined variables defined before the statement executes, as in a separate SET statement?

Comment: No. It's been defined on the fly.

Comment: Consider using inline views to initialize the variables. i would do e.g. `CROSS JOIN  ( SELECT @row_number := 0,  @atual := 0 ) i`

Comment: spencer7593, your comment really helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was: the @ variables seems to be initialized automatically when running direct on mysql cli, but not through mysqli_query.
One simple join on the subqueries did the job.

Thanks @spencer7593 for the insight.

The final sql:

```
UPDATE 
   frequencia 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            *,
            @row_number_aux := 
            CASE
               WHEN
                  @atual_aux = disciplina_id 
               THEN
                  @row_number_aux + 1 
               ELSE
                  1 
            END
            AS "row_number", @atual_aux := disciplina_id AS "disciplina_atual" 
         FROM
            frequencia                     
            join (select @row_number_aux := 0, @atual_aux := 0) xxx

         WHERE
            frequencia.data > "2019-06-17" 
            AND frequencia.aluno_id IN 
            (
               8835, 5553, 3488, 7769, 143, 4406, 1472, 698, 8731, 5221, 4240, 4934, 8426, 8107, 5180, 2146, 5589, 4565
            )
      )
      frequencia_aux 
      ON frequencia.id = frequencia_aux.id 
   INNER JOIN
      (
         SELECT
            *,
            @row_number := 
            CASE
               WHEN
                  @atual = disciplina_id 
               THEN
                  @row_number + 1 
               ELSE
                  1 
            END
            AS "row_number", @atual := disciplina_id AS "disciplina_atual" 
         FROM
            (
               SELECT
                  disciplina_id,
                  data,
                  tempo,
                  turma_id 
               FROM
                  frequencia 
               WHERE
                  data > "2019-06-17" 
                  AND turma_id = "87" 
               GROUP BY
                  data,
                  disciplina_id,
                  tempo 
            )
            frequencia 
           join (select @row_number := 0, @atual := 0) xxx
      )
      aux 
      ON frequencia_aux.disciplina_id = aux.disciplina_id 
      AND frequencia_aux.data = aux.data 
      AND frequencia_aux.row_number = aux.row_number
SET
   frequencia.turma_id = aux.turma_id,
   frequencia.tempo = aux.tempo
```